# What happened to AWS Sentinel2 website?

Tags: sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

**edit**:

This question was about a free service that no longer exists for viewing Sentinel 2 data from AWS before the 'requester pays' condition was put in place.

If you want to find out more on how to access data yourself consider the answer to [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/303540/download-and-browse-sentinel-data-from-aws) or go to Sentinel Hub forum by Sinergise (the company that ESA pays to manage this data)

https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/c/aws-sentinel

specifically this thread

https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/t/changes-of-the-access-rights-to-l1c-bucket-at-aws-public-datasets-requester-pays/172

Comment: There seems to be special forum for Sentinel2 AWS https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/c/aws-sentinel. Maybe this is relevant thread https://forum.sentinel-hub.com/t/changes-of-the-access-rights-to-l1c-bucket-at-aws-public-datasets-requester-pays/172/6

Answer (score 1):

[Sinergise](https://www.sinergise.com/en) developed a [Sentinel Hub](https://www.sentinel-hub.com/) from where you can access [EO Browser](https://apps.sentinel-hub.com/eo-browser/?lat=46.504&lng=14.521&zoom=9) and browse as well as manipulate several sensors data.

Answer (score -2):

OpenWeather company have free satellite image of Sentinel-2. New images every 2-4 days and historical archive. You can easily get them using by our API https://agromonitoring.com/api/images. More information on website https://agromonitoring.com/ or in blog.